# How to check whether a service is running or not on Linux Mint

Tags: service, startup, status, linux-mint

How do I check whether a service is running or not on Linux Mint?

If that service is not running, I need to start it.

I have tried using

```
service <service-name> status
```

But for some services it is not returning any results.

`service --status-all` is not of much use either as it has `?` marks for some services.

Answer (score 8):

In Linux Mint 16 and 17, by default you should be able to use a combination of `sudo service <options>` and `sudo update-rc.d <options>`.

For example, to get a list of services, try:

`sudo service --status-all` (as you said).

On the displayed list, `+` = started, `-` = stopped and `?` is unknown.

To disable a listed service from starting at boot try:

```
sudo update-rc.d <service name> disable
```

To enable a service to start at boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d <service name> enable
```

There are many more options for `update-rc.d`, try `man update-rc.d` for details.

A service that has been disabled (or stopped) can be manually started with:

```
sudo service <service name> start
```

A service (started manually or at boot) can stopped with:

```
sudo service <service name> stop
```

Many services also have other options like `restart` and `force-reload` but all should have `start` and `stop`.

Answer (score 3):

- `update-rc.d` - install and remove System-V style init script links
- `sysv-rc-conf` - Run-level configuration for SysV like init script links

`sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf`

`sudo sysv-rc-conf`

[image: sysv-rc-conf]

- `top`  - display Linux processes

`sudo apt-get install top`

[image]

- `bum`        Boot-Up Manager - Graphical runlevel configuration tool

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of starting and managing services in Ubuntu/Mint. The old System-V style init way and upstart.

Your service can either be managed by upstart or not. If you don't see it with 
`service --status-all` that means it is. To list services managed by upstart, use `sudo initctl list`. For more info, check the man pages for `service` and `initctl`.